# How fix linux space issue?

Tags: linux, disk-space

I am getting this error on my linux server . I am not much familiar with space issue. Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory                                                                                            file:
  /tmp/hsperfdata_XXXXX/29161
 Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.
```

My  Filesystem looks like this.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2             25G   24G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: So your disk is full?  100% used it says right there?

Comment: @John Zwinck Yes, i can see it, but how to make the disk space available ? I am scared to clear/delete any files.

Comment: Since this is a programming questions site, what's your programming question?  How to overcome your fear of deleting files?  Two solutions that come to mind are an external hard drive, or a psychiatrist.

Comment: file in /tmp can be removed most of the time without problem. You will probably need to reboot (if you delete X's socket). You probably have many other thing no working if / is full.

Comment: Time to unleash `du`. ;) You can’t magically make the disk bigger (well, the admin could, seeing how it’s a Xen virtual disk), so you’ll have to delete stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is full, 100% utilization... You need to increase the disk size available and adjust the partitions, or delete some things.

What can you delete is the key question, that's a tough question... Check `/home/(user)/.Trash` first, then almost any `tmp` directory's contents or temp file is safe to delete (start with /tmp delete the contents, not the folder), almost anything in /var/log is save to delete.

There are some very simple tools and guides on the Internet for clearing up space in Linux, [MaryRoseCook's tutorial](https://maryrosecook.com/blog/post/freeing-disk-space-on-your-linux-server) is about as simple as it gets:

> To find out where disk space is being used:
>
> 1. Get to the root of your machine by running `cd /`
> 2. Run `sudo du -h --max-depth=1`
> 3. Note which directories are using a lot of disk space.
> 4. cd into one of the big directories.
> 5. Run `ls -l` to see which files are using a lot of space. Delete any you don’t need.
> 6. Repeat steps 2 to 5.

Also, you didn't state any specific distro you were using, but here are some general thoughts:

Clean you package manager's cache, for example in Debian/Ubuntu based distributions use `sudo apt clean` to clear out the apt package manager cache. Also, in apt based package management you can also use `sudo apt autoremove` to clear out old/unused applications and dependencies that are not needed, in some cases this can be quite significant. Other distros that use different package management have similar tools to do these same actions.

Delete old kernels... These kernels, and the associated libraries and source for building modules, can take significant space.

These simple things can regain significant space. Otherwise, contact your administrator (which may be yourself) and decide if you just need more space for your operating system.

*EDIT: I didn't notice this was a really old post, the answer may or may not be relevant due to the age of the question.*

Answer (score 0):

May be the temporary location that was used has got full. Try using some other location. Also, check the #inodes free in each partition and clear up some space.
There is no need to change the /tmp at OS level. We want nutch and hadoop to use some other location for storing temp files.

It's confusing, but hadoop.tmp.dir is used as the base for temporary directories locally, and also in HDFS. The document isn't great, but mapred.system.dir is set by default to "${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/system", and this defines the Path on the HDFS where where the Map/Reduce framework stores system files.

If you want these to not be tied together, you can edit your mapred-site.xml such that the definition of mapred.system.dir is something that's not tied to ${hadoop.tmp.dir}